# How to add code autocompletion to PyCharm when working with graphical .ui components

Tags: python, user-interface, autocomplete, pycharm, pyqt5

In VisualStudio, when you access a component through a dot, you are immediately offered methods and data that belong to this class. In PyCharm, when working with .ui files, it feels like you are accessing a black box about the contents of which nothing is known. Are there any plugins or other ways to autocomplete text for graphical components in PyCharme like VisualStudio does?

Comment: Are you talking about files generated with pyuic or dynamically loaded with `loadUi()`?

Comment: @musicamante `loadUi()`

Comment: The autocomplete won't work without the files generated by pyuic. Try this approach instead: [Integrate Qt Designer and PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58599351/984421).